# Django datepicker in ModelForm shows incorrect date with instance

Tags: python, django, datepicker, modelform

I have a ModelForm in forms.py as -

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
from_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%d-%m-%Y'],
                           label='From Date',
                           widget=forms.TextInput(
                                   attrs={'placeholder': 'Select a date', 'class': 'datepicker'})
                           )
to_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%d-%m-%Y'],
                           label='To Date',
                           widget=forms.TextInput(
                                   attrs={'placeholder': 'Select a date', 'class': 'datepicker'})
                           )

class Meta:
    model = MyModel
    fields = ['from_date', 'to_date', 'reason']
```

And the related js -

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.5.2/flatpickr.min.js"></script>
$('.datepicker').flatpickr({
    dateFormat: "d-m-Y",
    allowInput:true,
});
```

With a create form, everything works fine and object gets created successfully. However, on editing the object, the initial date shown on the form is incorrect (Probably the %Y-%m-%d gets parsed as %d-%m-%Y). How to show the correct date in the update form? I tried setting the initial in `__init__` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use DateInput, not TextInput, along with the `format` attribute.

```
from_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%d-%m-%Y'],
                           label='From Date',
                           widget=forms.DateInput(
                                   format='%d-%m-%Y',
                                   attrs={'placeholder': 'Select a date', 'class': 'datepicker'})
                           )
```

(Remember, the field is responsible for input validation, the widget is responsible for display.)